# Proving subvector spaces

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Here is what I'm being asked to do:

Consider the vector space $F$($R$, $R$) of functions from $R$ to $R$. Show that the set $D$ of differentiable functions from $R$ to $R$ is a subvector space of $F$($R$, $R$), and that the set $P$ of polynomials functions on $R$ is a subvector space of $F$($R$, $R$). Determine for the vector spaces $F$($R$, $R$), $C$($R$, $R$), $P$, and $D$ all subvector space relations.

To prove that a set is a subvector space I believe I need to show that zero exists in the set and that the set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. What I am more confused about is the last part of the question. How can I determine all subvector space relations?

Comment: I guess you have to find what subspace includes what other subspace, and prove it. For example, all polynomials are differentiable, so $P\subset D$.

Comment: @Augustin Wouldn't all of them be a subset of $F$? It seems to me that I have to prove that $P$ and $D$ are subvector spaces of $F$ and the set of all continuous functions would have to be a subset of $F$ as well but this seems redundant.

Comment: Yes they are all subvector spaces of $F$. We actually have $P\subset D\subset C\subset F$ and for each inclusion, there is alors a "subvector space" relation.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, for instance, to show that the subset $\mathcal{C}(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R})$ of $\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R})$ is a subspace you'll need to show that it is closed under addition and that it is closed under scalar multiplication and that it contains the identity. In this case, the sum of two continuous functions is a continuous function, hence it is closed under addition. The same can be stated for the scalar multiplication, and lastly, the “zero” function $0:x\mapsto 0$ is continuous. Hence all the three conditions are satisfied, and so $\mathcal{C}(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R})$ is a subspace of the vector space $\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R})$.

As for the last question, they want you to establish a hierarchy between these sets, in this case we would have: $$\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})\subsetneq\mathcal{D}(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R})\subsetneq\mathcal{C}(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R})\subsetneq\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R}).$$